# compile error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am the most basic of newbies to Ruby on Rails; I just picked it up and decided to play around a bit. I've encountered an issue that seems to work for some but not for me...

Created an arbitrary page, with an useless sign up link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

Viewing the page produces the following:

```
compile error
... /home.html.erb:11: syntax error, unexpected ':'
...                        class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" )...
```

This seems to work for others, but again, not for me. I've played around with it a bit but can't seem to get rid of it without removing the line altogether. The link is arbitrary but I would like to see it work if possible. I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: you need to include your code in `home.html.erb`.  If the part that causes the error is `class:`, try to change that to `:class =>`.  You might be using `ruby 1.8.7` where the `key: value` syntax is only available for 1.9.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using Ruby 1.9 hash syntax when you're using Ruby 1.8. Switching it to `=>` will fix this problem.